# Access sql query help - football database

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I need to create a query that shows the average attendance by conference when at least one team played in a game.

I can get average for team1 no problem. [Relationships screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpXQT.png)

[image]

```
SELECT Conference.ConferenceName, AVG(Game.Attendance) AS AVG_ATT
FROM (Conference INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID])
INNER JOIN Game ON School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team1]
GROUP BY Conference.ConferenceName;
```

The problem I am having is adding Team2 to the equation.

Comment: I thought the below method was working but if a game contains 2 teams from the same conference the attendance gets added twice.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem case - can you ask a new question with sample data that shows the problem? Please use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more complicated JOIN expressions than `Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field2` in Access SQL, but note that you won't be able to edit the query in the Query designer.

```
SELECT Conference.ConferenceName, AVG(Game.Attendance) AS AVG_ATT
FROM (Conference INNER JOIN School ON Conference.[ConferenceID] = School.[ConferenceID])
INNER JOIN Game ON (
       School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team1] 
    OR School.[SchoolID] = Game.[Team2]
  )
GROUP BY Conference.ConferenceName;
```

Comment: I thought this is what i was looking for but the average is not correct. if a game contains 2 teams from the same conference it should only add the attendance to the calculation once, but it appears to add the attendance twice.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to a team table and it made the queries very easy.  I liked having Team1 and team2 inside the game table i might try your method to see how well it works.

[game and  team screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwMBR.png)